# Recreation of entity classes

Tags: jpa

I try to run a web application with hibernate, spring and jpa on netbeans 8.0.1, but now I'm stuck on this exception when compiling app...Here's the error below:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-    compile) on project SMSXxxxx: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
error: Problem with Filer: Attempt to recreate a file for type  com.equitel.smsmanager.entities.TextMessageContent_
error: Problem with Filer: Attempt to recreate a file for type com.smsmanager.entities.SmsUser_
```

Here is the persistence unit, I have only one in my project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="SMSManagerPU" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<jta-data-source>java:/jboss/datasources/SMSManagerDS</jta-data-source>
<class>com.smsmanager.entities.Approval</class>
<class>com.smsmanager.entities.Changelog</class>
<class>com.smsmanager.entities.Contacts</class>
<class>com.smsmanager.entities.Dispatches</class>
<class>com.smsmanager.entities.MessageSchedule</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have not managed to fix this error , could you help me fix this?

Comment: Do you mind showing us also the pom.xml file?

Comment: Did it work in eclipse ???

Comment: Is there any solution for this problem after more than 6 years now?

Answer (score 6):

For some reasons, there is a dependency in `pom.xml` that in my case caused the problem. Look for it and delete it:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.1.Final</artifactId>
        <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This could be a bug in Netbeans.
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=183779

Comment: Removing that dependency will likely cause other problems such as the jpa metamodel not being generated any more.

Answer (score 0):

Check your pom.xml file `maven-compiler-plugin` is added or not. If it is not there add plugin as shown in below.

```
<plugin>
<inherited>true</inherited>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>              
</plugin>
```

You can find root cause by using `mvn clean install -X` in cmd prompt.

Check in your `pom.xml` file the version of java mentioned there and check which version of java is mentioned in the **$JAVA_HOME** 
environment variable . Both should be the same.

Check this also

- May be its Java Compiler issue.
- May be issue with downloading the jar

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me:
Try to remove the :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.1.Final</artifactId>
    <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then add a maven profile with activation and dependency

> ```
> <profiles>
> <profile>
>     <id>profile-JPA-Gen</id>
>     <activation>
>         <property>
>             <name>activate_gen</name>
>             <value>true</value>
>         </property>
>     </activation>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
>         <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
>         <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
>     </dependency>
> </profile> </profiles>
> ```

Run once `mvn install -P profile-JPA-Gen` only to generate the relevant classes, and then use `mvn clean install`.