# Recreation of jpa metamodels

Tags: java, spring, jpa, gradle, intellij-idea

I want to use JPA meta-models in my project. I added required dependency to my project, added generation to JavaCompile task and meta-models are successfully generated. If I want to run the code again, It doesn't compile. It fails with:

***Error:java: Problem with Filer: Attempt to recreate a file for type project.models.AdministrationUser_***

for every single meta-model. I am running it in Idea as spring boot run. If I use gradle task boot run than it will run just fine, no problem, but I need Idea run, because I need to set active profiles. It also shows, that problem is probably not in code but somewhere in run task configuration but I have no idea what to change and I tried to change several things but I'm just firing blanks.

I'm using Gradle 5.4.1., Idea 2019.2 and Java 11.

Here are important parts of my `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api")
    annotationProcessor("org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen")
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.annotationProcessorGeneratedSourcesDirectory = 
    file("src/generated/java")
}

sourceSets {
    generated {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/generated/java']
        }
    }
}
```

Something similar was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27190865/recreation-of-entity-classes) but one answer suggest to delete hibernate-jpamodelgen what (if I understand it correctly) seems like absurd solution - because it wont work if you delete it. Other answer suggest using some maven plugin, so not an option for me either.

I'm stuck on this problem for a longer time, have no one to talk to about it and I'm completely out of ideas so I'm pretty desperate and any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, make modifications to your `build.gradle`.

You point to the wrong directory in the `sourceSets` section. Fix it:

```
sourceSets {
    generated {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/generated']
        }
    }
}
```

Then make further improvements:

With Gradle 5.2 and Intellij 2019.1 `annotationProcessors` is the only piece of configuration you need. See https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-apt-plugin/blob/v0.21/README.md

Get rid of

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.annotationProcessorGeneratedSourcesDirectory = 
    file("src/generated/java")
}

sourceSets {
    generated {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/generated/java']
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, consider delegating your build and test tasks to Gradle (this is now the default). Go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Build and run using Gradle

Comment: delegating build to Gradle fixed the problem, so thanks, I used that. Anyway, I knew gradle works fine even with the set up I already had and I wanted to know why IDEA dont. I still cant figure out this.